# How to get list of installed/enabled modules ready for repopulating new site with drush module installation?

Tags: 7, drush

When doing `drush pm-list` I get a whole list of modules but too much info also, like this:

Mail               Privatemsg filter (privatemsg_filter)          7.x-1.4
Mail               Privatemsg Limits (privatemsg_limits)          7.x-1.4
Mail               Privatemsg roles (privatemsg_roles)            7.x-1.4`

I have to edit in notepad++ and run macros...

I want the module list, but ONLY drush module names X_Y

Is there a way to get a clean list like:

module_a
module_b
module_c

ONLY

And then can use it as:

```
drush en module_a module_b module_c
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, got it working, commands to use are:

```
drush pm-list --type=module --status=enabled --no-core --format=list
```

and then you can use the:

```
edit>>mark>>copy
```

from drush console.

Answer (score 15):

```
drush pm-list --status="enabled" --pipe
```

> - `--status="enabled"` Filter by extension status. Choices: `enabled`, `disabled` and/or '`not installed`'. You can use multiple comma separated values. (i.e. `--status="disabled,not installed"`).
> - `--pipe` Equivalent to `--format=list`.
> - `--format="list"` Select output format. Available: `table`, `csv`, `json`, `list`, `var_export`, `yaml`. Default is `table`.

Comment: Interesting! Though I'm a very little bit confused: if you would change `--pipe` to `--format="list"` , would you then get the very same result?

Comment: Yes. You get the same result.

Comment: Merci for confirming !

Answer (score 2):

If the purpose of your question is to repopulate a new site (as in your question title), then you may want to look at the [drush make-generate](http://drushcommands.com/drush-7x/make/make-generate) command.

No need for things like editing and/or running macros (though you could edit the result if for whatever reason you still have to do so).

Refer to [How to use Drush Make in your daily routine](http://www.webomelette.com/how-use-drush-make-your-daily-routine) for an interesting article about it also.

Comment: I tried this command:  drush pm-list type=module status=enabled --no-core --format=list it works, but only ALL contrib modules, the "status=enabled" command gets ignored, am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You can obtain the list using the [module_list()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21module.inc/function/module_list/7.x) function

> Returns a list of currently active modules.
>
> Usually, this returns a list of all enabled modules. When called early
>   on in the bootstrap, it will return a list of vital modules only
>   (those needed to generate cached pages).
>
> All parameters to this function are optional and should generally not
>   be changed from their defaults. Parameters
>
> $refresh: (optional) Whether to force the module list to be
>   regenerated (such as after the administrator has changed the system
>   settings). Defaults to FALSE.
>
> $bootstrap_refresh: (optional) When $refresh is TRUE, setting
>   $bootstrap_refresh to TRUE forces the module list to be regenerated
>   using the reduced set of modules loaded in "bootstrap mode" for cached
>   pages. Otherwise, setting $refresh to TRUE generates the complete list
>   of enabled modules.
>
> $sort: (optional) By default, modules are ordered by weight and module
>   name. Set this option to TRUE to return a module list ordered only by
>   module name.
>
> $fixed_list: (optional) If an array of module names is provided, this
>   will override the module list with the given set of modules. This will
>   persist until the next call with $refresh set to TRUE or with a new
>   $fixed_list passed in. This parameter is primarily intended for
>   internal use (e.g., in install.php and update.php).